# AngularJS - Insert info dinamically into controller according to a ng-repeat from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a very simple example in order to make it easier to understand.

Here I have ng-repeat that calls a template. This template has its own controller. 
However, the controller of the template needs to be injected some data from the service in each ng-repeat. In this demonstration it has to be the answer to the question.
How can I achieve that?

```
  <div ng-repeat="fighter in fighters">
    <div ng-if="fighter.state">
      {{fighter.question}}
      <div ng-include="'template.html'" ng-controller="Controller2"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
```

If you want to see the whole demo working, check this plunker:

[DEMO PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/R3lDIv6F4rapvhr9qq7Q?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **template.html** create a `ng-init` function and pass the obj

```
<div ng-controller="Controller2" ng-init="getAnwser(fighter)">
  <div>
    <!-- Inserir pergunta que vem da base de dados aqui-->
    <input type="text" ng-model="answer"  />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="checkAnswer()">
      ANSWER
    </button>
    <div ng-show="showAnswer">Correct</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

in **controller2** implement the function

```
$scope.getAnwser = function(obj){
  console.log(obj.answer)
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qLkNpGETvezHVLxxu1m2?p=preview)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/xHgFWPyJ5wWlGWMlUVGK?p=preview

check this plunker. Is it possible to wear it outside the function on the same controller?